What is the connection between a regular language's pumping number, and the number of states of an equivalent deterministic automaton?
I am self-studying Automata and Formal Languages from a set of past lecture notes, and I have a question about the proof of the Regular Pumping Lemma. The proof defines $D$ to be a deterministic automaton which accepts a language $L$. It is then proved that $|D|$ is the pumping number of $L$. What I don't understand is that multiple DFA's accept $L$, so is the pumping number the size of the minimal one?
If I find a DFA which accepts $L$, is all I have an upper bound on the pumping number (unless the DFA is irreducible)?

Usually, we care about a pumping constant as the size of every automaton (including nondeterministic ones) for the language can be used as such. If your goal is to find the minimal natural $p$ that can serve as a pumping constant, then it can be smaller than the size of a minimal automaton for the language. Try to come up with an example, here is a hint:
The idea is that the pumping lemma proof requires $p$ to be large enough so that an accepting run of the automaton on a word $w$ in the language passes through a cycle when $w$ is of length at least $p$. Choosing $p = |Q|$ is sufficient (so it serves as an upper bound on the minimal pumping constant), but we can choose $p$ to be the length of the longest simple path from an initial to an accepting state, and that can be smaller than the number of states.
Edit: of-course, there are examples where you can have a pumping constant even smaller than the condition I wrote above (as mentioned in the comments). What I wanted to emphasize is that choosing $p = |Q|$ does not imply minimality of $p$, yet, is sufficient to conclude the pumping lemma.

Thanks! I thought the phrasing around the proof was slightly odd, this explains it

You're welcome.

I think the pumping number can be even smaller than the length of the longest simple path. For example, consider (abcdefg)+ -- any accepting string can be pumped, regardless of length, so presumably the minimal pumping number is 0. (In a sense, the entire restriction on string length has been moved into the language membership test itself.)

@DanielWagner Did not read your whole comment, but yes it can be smaller than that for sure. Edited the answer for clarity.
